# Getting JSON data from a database via an API, display more results

Tags: ios, json, api, textview

I am making an application for iOS. The application has to display results from an MYSQL database and I have an API between the app and the database. The database send valid JSON (this is in my browser):

[{"naam":"Maurice","id":2},{"naam":"Klaas","id":6},{"naam":"Mariska","id":8}]

But I cannot see more than one result in my application. I search for example "M" and it only resturns the first Maurice. I want the app to display also Mariska.

Can anyone explain my how to display more than one result, in this case, in my iOS application?

Thanks in advance,

Maurice.

Here more code:

```
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"rw_app_id"];
    [request setPostValue:voornaam forKey:@"voornaam"];
    [request setPostValue:deviceUniqueIdentifier forKey:@"device_id"];
    [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"test"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    // Hide keyword
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // Clear text field
    textView.text = @"";

    // Start hud
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Zoeken...";

    return TRUE;
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    if (request.responseStatusCode == 400) {
        textView.text = @"Invalid code";        
    }
     else if (request.responseStatusCode == 403) {
        textView.text = @"Code already used";
    }
     else if (request.responseStatusCode == 204) {
        textView.text = @"No content";
    }
     else if (request.responseStatusCode == 412) {
        textView.text = @"Precondition Failed";
    }
     else if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
        NSString *naam = [responseDict objectForKey:@"naam"];

       // if ([unlockCode compare:@"com.razeware.test.unlock.cake"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultaten: %@", naam];
      //  } else {
           // textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultaat: %@", unlockCode];
      //  }

    } 
    else {
        textView.text = @"Unexpected error API ERROR";
    }

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    textView.text = error.localizedDescription;
}

@end
```

`

Comment: Can you add more details about your code?

Comment: Include the code also

Comment: write your code in question (edit your question) not in comment.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I tried this code in my code but Xcode gives a undeclared identifier 'objjSSONParser'. I haven't used a SBJSON parser so this can be right. Do you know how I can fix this? or that I just have to install a SBJSON parser? (I ask my question here because I cannot ask me question @ you in your answer)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {    
     [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

      NSString *strResponse = [request responseString];
      SBJSON *objJSONParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
  NSDictionary *dictData = [objJSONParser objectWithString:strResponse error:nil];

      NSDictionary *dictResult = [dictData objectForKey: @"response"];
      NSLog(@"result Dict=%@",dictResult)      
      NSArray *arrTemp=(NSArray *)[dictData objectForKey:@"response"];
        NSLog(@"Array=%@",arrTemp)   

     //print both one by one is it work or not?
```

Comment: I tried this code in my code but Xcode gives a undeclared identifier 'objjSSONParser'. I haven't used a SBJSON parser so this can be right. Do you know how I can fix this? or that I just have to install a SBJSON parser?

Comment: This didn't work for my but I found another solution. I added a tableview for viewing more results.